# WIC (exif) metadata query syntax using MQL

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, exif, wic

The question is about the syntax of MQL (Metadata Query Language) in C#.

I've seen different kind of queries:

```
1) bitmapMetadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/{ushort=33434}"); // result
2) bitmapMetadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{ushort=33434}"); // null
3) bitmapMetadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/subifd:{ushort=33434}"); // result
4) bitmapMetadata.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/f00:{ushort=33434}"); // result
```

By using the syntax in line 1, 3 and 4 I get a result, the second one is not valid (though I see it in some code examples).

Now why is it that "subifd:" or "f00:" prefix also returns a valid result? The (sub)block "f00:" doesn't even exist. Is that part of the WIC MQL that just searches for the first valid result? 
Does it mean that constructing an exif query actually doesn't require subifd: or f00: prefix and it is recommended to always use the syntax in the first line?

Does the second line actually means something or just an invalid query?

On github I see several queries using e.g. {**uint**=*id*} instead of {**ushort**=*id*} for accessing **the same property**. Any recommendations here?

Hope someone can shine a light on this as after reading MS Docs I still have these questions.